# GuzzleHttp client is painfully slow when downloading large files

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to download a file from a server using GuzzleHttp client. but it turns out to be so slow. When I use the download link with a client like IDM or Aria2 its upto 2MB/sec. But when using Guzzle it's about 100KB/sec
Here's the code

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$sink = "path/to/sink";
$client ->get($url,[
    'sink'=>$sink,
    'progress'=>function($size,$dl,$up,$upt){
         echo "$dl/$size \n";
    },
  ]);
```

How can I speed up the download process?

*I've to use Guzzle because it's required by the Application I'm working on*

Comment: Try updating the version of cURL.

Comment: I'm using latest cURL available on Debian 10